# pandas dataframe groupby on multiindex

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas dataframe to read excel file and do some operation on that. I have a header with multiple rows, and now I want to group by a few column values. However I am not able to find the solution for this.

Sample Excel:

```
    name                     address         contact_info   
    first_name  last_name   street  city    mobile  email
1   AAA         BBB         XXX     YYY     102020  aaa@xyz.com
2   111         222         333     444     239393  bbb@xyz.com
3   BBB         333         XXX     dddd    102020  aaa@xyz.com
```

I want to group by street name and find values from other columns
I tried this but it's not able to find street as it's multiindex.

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", header=[0, 1], sheet_name="Sheet1")
print df.groupby("street", level=-1)[["first_name", "last_name", "email"]].apply(list)
```

Comment: It looks like you don't actually need the first row - kind of duplicate information. If you read it in WITHOUT that first row (header=1), or (skiprows=1), you won't have to deal with multi-indexing... making your job much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide lists of tuples everywhere:

```
cols = [
           ('name', 'first_name'), 
           ('name', 'last_name'), 
           ('contact_info', 'email')
]
df.groupby([('address', 'street')])[cols].apply(pd.Series.tolist)

# or, alternatively,
# df.groupby(df.address.street)[cols].apply(pd.Series.tolist)

(address, street)
333                            [[111, 222, bbb@xyz.com]]
XXX    [[AAA, BBB, aaa@xyz.com], [BBB, 333, aaa@xyz.c...
```

Tuples specify `MultiIndex` column selection.

Comment: I am getting the following error 
`TypeError: unbound method tolist() must be called with Series instance as first argument (got DataFrame instance instead)`

Comment: @GaurangShah Try `.apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())` instead.

Comment: @COLDSPEED is there any way to get the street (first column values) apart from doing this. `df.T.index.values.T.tolist()`

Comment: @GaurangShah What is your expected result? I'm not clear on that... by the way, you can also upvote answers if they were helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @jezrael Not justified... I've reversed it for you.