# pandas dataframe groupby conditional count on multi-level column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

Let's say we have dataframe like this

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(4, 4)),columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['exp0','exp1'],['rnd0','rnd1']],names=['experiments','rnd_runs']))

df['grp1','cat'] = ['A','A','B','B']
df['grp2','cat2'] = ['C','C','C','B']

experiments exp0            exp1            grp1 grp2
rnd_runs    rnd0    rnd1    rnd0    rnd1    cat cat2
0             66    92      98      17      A   C
1             83    57      86      97      A   C
2             96    47      73      32      B   C
3             46    96      25      83      B   B
```

I want to `count` values in `('exp0', 'rdn0')` column with `groupby` `('grp1','cat')`

So I tried;

```
df['exp0_cnt','rdn0'] = df.groupby([('grp1','cat')])[('exp0', 'rdn0')].apply(sum(x > 50 for x in df[(('exp0', 'rdn0'))]))
```

but getting the error

> TypeError: other must be a MultiIndex or a list of tuples

Here are the similar posts and I think I'm doing multi-level column callings with `tuples`.

[conditional on multi header pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409660/conditional-on-multi-header-pandas-dataframe)

[pandas dataframe groupby on multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917614/pandas-dataframe-groupby-on-multiindex)

[Better way for creating columns in a multi level columns pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533883/better-way-for-creating-columns-in-a-multi-level-columns-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only ways to select MultiIndex columns from a groupby is with a *list* of tuples or a MultiIndex (as indicated by the Error Message):

So, instead of `[('exp0', 'rdn0')]` it needs to be `[[('exp0', 'rnd0')]]`.

```
df['exp0_cnt', 'rdn0'] = (
    df.groupby([('grp1', 'cat')])[[('exp0', 'rnd0')]]
        #                         ^ needs to be a list of tuples
        .transform(lambda x: x.gt(50).sum())  # Some function that works
)
```

*I've also changed the apply function, because it seems to be missing the `lambda` so I made a guess as to an equivalent:

```
.apply(sum(x > 50 for x in df[(('exp0', 'rdn0'))])
```

To `transform` since it's being assigned back to the DataFrame:

```
.transform(lambda x: x.gt(50).sum())
```

`df`:

```
experiments exp0      exp1      grp1 grp2 exp0_cnt
rnd_runs    rnd0 rnd1 rnd0 rnd1  cat cat2     rdn0
0             66   92   98   17    A    C        2
1             83   57   86   97    A    C        2  # 2 values over 50 (in group)
2             96   47   73   32    B    C        1
3             46   96   25   83    B    B        1  # 1 values over 50 (in group)
```

---

**Please Note**: This means that a `SeriesGroupBy` cannot be created by selecting MultiIndex columns, only `DataFrameGroupBy` operations.

```
type(df.groupby([('grp1', 'cat')])[[('exp0', 'rnd0')]])
# <class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>
```

This will exclude a few operations like [`SeriesGroupBy.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html)

```
df.groupby([('grp1', 'cat')])[[('exp0', 'rnd0')]].unique()
```

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

However, we can force a `SeriesGroupBy` by Selecting the Series from the DataFrame and grouping by the Series values directly:

```
df[('exp0', 'rnd0')].groupby(df[('grp1', 'cat')]).unique()
#  ^ select specific column  ^ pass the Series to groupby directly
```

```
(grp1, cat)
A    [66, 83]
B    [96, 46]
Name: (exp0, rnd0), dtype: object
```